# Preventing CSRF using different HTTP methods?

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest, xss, csrf, csrf-protection

I use AJAX on my site and tokens to prevent CSRF.
Is there any sense to use different HTTP methods instead of POST to increase protection against CSRF? or any other attack?

**Assumption**:
We use different security tokens and a constant HTTP method. Why not make it variable?
If a bad guy sends data by POST method but a server waits PUT method from this particular user.

Comment: Why not [google](https://www.google.de/search?q=Cross-Site+Request+Forgery+prevention+methods) it?

Comment: its all about security tokens while i asked about HTTP methods

Comment: `An alternate defense which is particularly well suited for AJAX endpoints is the use of a custom request header. This defense relies on the same-origin policy (SOP) restriction that only JavaScript can be used to add a custom header, and only within its origin. By default, browsers don't allow JavaScript to make cross origin requests. A particularly attractive custom header and value to use is:` `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` Seems like a HTTP method to me. First article on google. Using only that as a check would be bad practice though.

Comment: Seems like an extra token in a custom header to me.

Answer (score 1):

From security point-of-view there is absolutely no difference how does data being transferred to server. So, answer is **No**.